# Adobe PDF Reader component (AcroPDF.dll) - is it possible to access table of contents and bookmarks from code?

Tags: .net, pdf, adobe, adobe-reader, axacropdf

I'm using the above DLL in my .NET project. It seems to make different functions accessible, but I can't find bookmarks and table of contents. Is it possible to access those?
Also, any manuals/guides available for this component?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, the automation interface of the free version is quite limited.  You'll get more with the retail edition.  The API manual [is here](http://partners.adobe.com/public/developer/en/acrobat/sdk/pdf/iac/IACReference.pdf).  Beware that the document is quite confuzzling, it mixes the docs for the freeware and retail edition.  Chapter 3 starts talking about COM specific stuff, the kind you could use from a .NET app.

Answer (score 0):

Also be aware the table may not exist in the PDF - PDf files do not generally preserve such structures unless you create them as Structured COntent.